# Objects field changes for unknown reason

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I am writing a program dealing with subnets.

In simpleIPaddress.class line 315, the object Ted's fullSubnetAddress = "111.111.111.111".

In simpleIPaddress.class line 317, the object Ted's fullSubnetAddress changes for some reason I can not figure out.  It changes to the as textAddress the field variable for the class.  textAddress is generated from the program earlier in the code when the simpleIPaddress address is initially created from user input.

After the first time the for loop is executed, Ted is changed permanently for the rest of the for loop.

In the code I am slowly populating an array.

```
SubnetItem ted = new SubnetItem(subnetNumber, fullSubnetAddress, fullStartHost,
    fullEndHost, fullBroadcastAddress);
this.subnetArray = new SubnetItem[totalSubnets];

for (int i = 0; i < subnetArray.length; i++)
{

    this.subnetArray[i] = ted; // line 315
    this.subnetArray[i].setSubnetNumber(i);
    System.out.println(ted.toString()); // line 317
    calculateStartingAddress(i);

    System.out.println(ted.toString());

    System.out.println(subnetArray[i].toString());

}
```

[Here is the full code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a70a6b3f2bdba48a4678) if that is needed.

Comment: If the code is too big, you should write a [mcve] instead. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create only one `SubnetItem` object, then inside the `for` loop you repeatedly modify that single object while assigning every element of the array to point at the object. By the time the loop is over, you have an array full of pointers to the same object, now having the last value assigned to it.

If you want every array element to have a different value, you need to create a separate object for each one. That is as simple as moving the `SubnetItem ted = new SubnetItem(...);` line down a few lines so that it is inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! I  got  it fixed.  I am kind of hazy what the problem was.   It is something I definitely to think about! A+